# Передача значений через SharedPreferences в реальном времени

Tags: java, android, android-shared-preferences

У меня на главном экране есть текст, вызывая настройки открывается `DialogFragment`, в котором я задаю размер текста, сохраняю полученные значения в `SharedPreferences`, а в `MainAcitivity` я получаю эти значения и передаю их в `TextView`, но изменения происходят только по закрытию `DialogFragment`.

Вопрос: возможно ли сделать так, чтобы передаваемые мною значения из `DialogFragment` в `SharedPreferences` передавались к`TextView` в режиме реального времени? То есть чтобы синхронно менялся текст в главном активити, размер которого я задаю в `DialogFragment` передвижением ползунка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да можно. Вам нужно зарегистрировать в активити/фрагменте слушатель изменения `SharedPreferences`. Его колбэк будет вызываться при каждом изменении в оных.

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
               .registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
               .unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {
        switch (key) {
            case "myPrefKey":
                textView.setTextSize(sharedPreferences.getDouble(key, 0));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```